# Format specifier for cuDoubleComplex variables for accessing files

Tags: cuda

In C , we can easily access file using `fprintf()` and `fscanf()` as shown below:

```
fp = fopen(“forces1.txt”, “w”);
for(h=0;h<147;h++)
{
fprintf(fp, “%f %f %f\n”, ForceX[h], ForceY[h], ForceZ[h]);
}
```

But I am using CUDA and my variables `ForceX[h]` etc are of type `cuDoubleComplex`. I want to ask two things:

1. Whether I am allowed to use `frintf` and `fscanf` in CUDA, if not then how to access files.
2. What will be the format specifier used in place of `%f` as my variable is not float.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/format-specifier-for-cudoublecomplex-variables-for-accessing-files/191576/2):

in `cuComplex.h` (which is in the CUDA include directory in your CUDA install) we can see the following typedef:

```
typedef double2 cuDoubleComplex;
```

and `double2` is a struct definition (in `vector_types.h`, same directory) that looks like this:

```
struct double2 {

  double x,y;
};
```

So now your question is a C or C++ question. You can print the elements (`.x`, `.y`) of that struct easily enough using the `%f` format specifier.

Yes, you can use `fprintf` and `fscanf` in CUDA host code, just like you would in ordinary host code.